# Tensorflow: Define a conv2d-like operation

Tags: c++, tensorflow, convolution

I want to define a new operation which should work the same way `tf.conv2d` works. Looking at the documentation, I should implement `Compute(OpKernelContext* context)` member method of my new operation class. As far as I understood, `conv2d` is defined in `conv_ops.cc`. However, the documentation showcases a rather too simple operator (`ZeroOutOp`) and `conv_ops.cc` has a lot of dependencies. I couldn't find good documentation as to how the implementation was carried out?
Any ideas where I can find documentation about tensorflow source codes? Any tutorials that show how to implement a rather complicated operation?